# Search the row number un SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLITE (so no row_number)

Here is my database call : tableau

```
ID | Nom  | Score
---|------|------
1  | Clem | 50
2  | Caro | 60
3  | Flo  | 55
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM tableau ORDER BY Score DESC
```

And here is what I get:

```
ID | Nom  | Score
---|------|------
2  | Caro | 60
3  | Flo  | 55
1  | Clem | 50
```

But I would like to get the Row number of 'Flo" after its sorted in descending order

But I don't know how to do it...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableau ORDER BY Score DESC **WHERE** Nom = 'Flo';`

Can you try above query ?

Comment: I edited my post, I need the row number when order by Score, but not all the data of 'Flo'

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM tableau ORDER BY Score DESC **WHERE** Nom = 'Flo'; `

I hope this works for you.